# MySQL Connector / C++ Issue

Tags: c++, mysql, c, linux

I'm creating an application which makes use of the `MySQL C++ Connector`, the application compiles and runs fine on my `development machine (Fedora 15`), however when I compile and run on my other two machines (CentOS 6 and RHEL 6) it gets to the MySQL code, hangs for a moment, then dies with "Floating point exception (core dumped)".

I'm compiling the application statically.

gdb output:

```
    Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
    0x00000034c4477833 in sYSTRIm (av=0x34c478ae80, p=<value optimized out>,
    have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3469 3469      
    extra = ((top_size - pad - MINSIZE + (pagesz-1)) / pagesz - 1) * pagesz;
```

The exception is being thrown by the get_driver_instance function and seems to have something to do with "`getservbyname ()`"

Comment: Can we see some code around the problem area?

Comment: Code and a stack traceback would both be helpful :)  SUGGESTION: compile your app with "-g" (to include debug info) and run it in gdb.  You should get a clear stack traceback.  Cut/paste the traceback, and the relevant portion of your code just before the crash occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled your application as static?

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=644673

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=597578